# Pegar dados json do php com javascript

Tags: php, json

Olá, estou tentando montar um grafico dinamico com charts.js, os dados estão no meu banco de dados, retornei esses dados em uma variavel decodificada em json, que me retorna o seguinte:

```
[{"id_requisicao":"1","0":"1"},{"id_requisicao":"3","0":"3"},{"id_requisicao":"8","0":"8"},{"id_requisicao":"11","0":"11"},{"id_requisicao":"4","0":"4"},{"id_requisicao":"9","0":"9"}]
```

Tenho no meu arquivo dash.php o javascript com o charts mas não consigo pegar esses dados, alguem pode me ajudar?

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: <?php echo $exibiDash ?>,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `<?php $exibiDash ?>` isso não significa nada, precisa aplicar um `echo` ou simplesmente `<?=`

Comment: Tinha esquecido de colocar o echo mas mesmo assim não funcionou, aparece só a tela em branco, sem informações nem nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui descobrir, a versão do meu charts.js estava desatualizada e não funcionava.
e eu tive que colocar no options o nome das minhas chaves x e y.

```
 parsing: {
                    xAxisKey: 'nome',
                    yAxisKey: 'valor'
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode converter esses dados com `json_encode()` do lado do php, passar para um objeto javascript com `JSON.parse()`

```
<?php
$json = json_encode($seu_array);
?>
<script>
   datasets: [{
      data: JSON.parse('<?= $json ?>')
   }]
```

Espero ter ajudado =D

Comment: Não funcionou, a pagina aparece em branco

Comment: tenta criar uma variável no escopo global da página desse jeito q eu falei, e recuperar ela no console pra ver qual é o conteúdo, pq deveria funcionar, então talvez o erro esteja em outro lugar. Se no console ela não estiver `undefined`, o problema eh no chart, se estiver undefined o problema é no php